# How do I override the results from an django API query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm very new to Django, so this might seem basic.

I have 2 models:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField()

class Foo(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True)
    foo_name = models.CharField()
```

Foo.brand can be null. Now when an API query is made on Foo, I want to include results where the brand's name matches but also where Foo.brand is null

If Foo looks like this:

```
Foo.brand, Foo.foo_name
1, "apple"
3, "orange"
1, "mango"
null, "grape"
```

/api/foo?brand=1 should return apple, mango and grape. How can I get this? I tried reading similar questions, it sounds like I need to override the viewset, but wasn't sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with override `get_queryset` method in your view class and use `Q` operator for creating `or` condition. You need to brand id is equal or null condition :

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    foos = Foo.objects.all()
    brand_id = self.request.query_params.get('brand')
    if brand_id:
        foos = Foo.objects.filter(Q(brand_id__isnull=True)|Q(brand_id=brand_id))
    return foos
```